# In Android, play the music of the data/data path

Tags: android, media, playback

`/data/data/com.example/files/received/1386403084460/Over the horizon_2013.mp3`

Is it possible to play the media files from the above path without making public copy?

My app created the com.example and its paths, trying to play it using other available media players. The device is not rooted.

FYI:
I get these errors,

> Sound Player: Unable to find item,
>
> Google Play Music: Couldn't play the track you requested.

I am reading this post, can this problem be fixed using Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE?

http://www.grokkingandroid.com/how-to-correctly-store-app-specific-files-in-android/

Comment: Depends on many things. Is `com.example` the application that will play music ? If no, is device rooted ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do that without root, because the data-folder is only for your app. Other apps like Google Play Music don't have access to your path, that's why they can't find your media file.

You need to copy the file to the sdcard or root the device

Comment: can this problem be fixed using Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE?

Comment: yes, this is possible... it is explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7710628/2829009

Answer (score 0):

Apps cannot use the path directly. But you could use a [ContentProvider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html) and grant a uri-permission for those files. Then you could pass this uri on to other apps via intent.